# How to avoid error upgrading Nuxt 2 to Nuxt Bridge

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-bridge, nuxtjs3

I am currently keen to updating my existing Nuxt 2 project to Nuxt Bridge as documented here:

https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/bridge

As for my nuxt.config file I used `module.exports = { //config }`

Exchanging it with the:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from '@nuxt/bridge'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // Your existing configuration
})
```

leads to a webpack error for me because of the "@nuxtjs/firebase" [module](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/getting-started):

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you do this config https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/deployment/firebase/  for firebase deployment ?

Comment: Not yet, anyway, Nuxt somehow needs to know the firebare project credentials like apiKey, authDomain, etc., I don't think this will help, since I need the module in my nuxt.config

Answer (score 0):

You must specify an alias for tslib:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from '@nuxt/bridge'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  alias: {
    tslib: 'tslib/tslib.es6.js'
  }
})
```

Follow this issue: https://github.com/nuxt/bridge/issues/25